# Create specific LoginError asp.net

Tags: asp.net, authentication

I'm using the LoginPage by .net 4.5.
When the fields are empty I get an error in red which say I can't connect.
What I want to do, is when I enter username and passwords, I try to log into DB, and if I get false, I want a custom error which says I can't log into DB.
Here is the code:

```
protected void LoginButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!DBHandle.DBConnect(UserLogin.UserName, UserLogin.Password))
        {
        }
    }

    protected void UserName_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    protected void UserLogin_LoginError(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        UserLogin.FailureText = "asdad";
    }
```

What I have to put in the condition, that cause to get to LoginError?

Thanks!

Comment: Exception is depending on how you access your database. For example, Entity Framework throws EntityException. Even then I'm not comfortable to showing database connection error to a user instead I'll redirect to custom error page.

Comment: But how I can show error in the failuretext? I mean, that not only empty fields will cause the failure.

Comment: Use try catch. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dszsf989(v=VS.71).aspx